# How to close gap between python contour plot and colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I have made a contour plot and set plt.axis = 'square'. This has caused a significant gap between the plot and the color bar. I have been struggling to find a way to close this gap. How can you choose the distance between a contour plot and its color bar? How can you close this gap up to the point that they are touching?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
data = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]
plt.contourf(data)
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel('y label')
plt.ylabel('x label')
plt.axis('square')
```

Comment: Did you try `plt.colorbar(...., pad=0.01)`? Default is `0.15`. [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the `pad` attribute of plt.colorbar, and set it to -0.2 to align it with the plot itself. In case you want the colorbar bigger/smaller, you can also use the `shrink` attribute. More info [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

data = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]
plt.contourf(data)
plt.colorbar(pad = -0.2)

plt.xlabel('y label')
plt.ylabel('x label')
plt.axis('square')
```

Output:

[image]